invertibility of overcomplete system of non linear equations
I am currently working on a research problem involving 8 nonlinear equations in 5 variables. While these variables are all real, the equations themselves are complex in general. A colleague has mentioned that it may be impossible to invert these equations. However, I believe that with the extra information provided by 3 additional equations, solutions should exist as long as they do not contradict the previous 5 equations. Considering that these equations are nonlinear, I am unsure if the same rules of linearity apply for determining completeness. Nonlinear equations can have multiple solutions for a single variable, unlike linear equations which typically have only one solution (eg. $x^2 = 1$)
With that said, I am curious to know whether a system of 8 equations in 5 variables is generally solvable (assuming no inconsistencies). If you have any references on this topic, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share them with me.

What do you mean you say that system of nonlinear equations is consistent?
